# Refreshing fragment which is not in focus in viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a dynamic viewpager which has a play button on every fragment which changes into pause button on click.

Now what i am trying to do is that when user clicks on play button in any other fragment the play button in last playing fragment should refresh from pause to play i.e i want that play button active only in one fragment at a time rest should be in their default state.

I tried doing this with following code

```
      pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            previous =  current;
            current = position;



            try{
                if(position!=0)
                {
                    SwipeFragItem yourFragment =      (SwipeFragItem)mPageAdapter.getItem(previous);
                    yourFragment.refresh();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Crashlytics.logException(e);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

which do my task in 70% of the times but it does not refresh in 30% of the cases. I have ensured that it gets executed in these 30% of the cases and it does not throw any exception.

If you find my approach not appropriate please suggest any other way.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way i can think of is using event bus. Something like:
[Greenbot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

By registering all your fragments that you add in the view pager to listen to an event that gets triggered when the play button is pressed, all fragments will be notified. The event will obviously need to have an identifier so you know which fragment's play button was pressed. If its not from the same fragment, you can then set the button back to default state. Again, this is just one way i can think of.